# Android Chrome cookies all suddenly disappeared

Tags: chrome-for-android, cookies

This morning all the cookies seem to have disappeared from Chrome on my 'phone. When I log in again they stay, so it's not a bug or settings problem I think. They definitely have not all expired at the same time. History is fine, it's just the cookies. Can't find any references to this particular issue elsewhere.

Comment: Did you find the reason why it happened?

Comment: No, though I did wonder whether it was related to a Chrome update